# How to load weights with TPU strategy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

```
with strategy.scope():
    model = transformer(vocab_size=VOCAB_SIZE,
                        num_layers=NUM_LAYERS,
                        units=UNITS,
                        d_model=D_MODEL,
                        num_heads=NUM_HEADS,
                        is_encoder=True,
                        dropout=DROPOUT)
    
    model.load_weights("path")
```

I get error:

InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on path: UNIMPLEMENTED: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: 'path')

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You need to use Cloud Storage (GCS), which is a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) service.

As stated in the Cloud TPU documentation (https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting/trouble-tf#cannot_use_local_filesystem), TPU servers do not have access to your local storage; they can only see files in GCS buckets.

You need to place all the data used for training a model (or inference, depending on your intent) in a GCS bucket, including pretrained weights and the dataset. Note that GCS is a paid service, albeit [not very pricey](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-examples) (and first-time users get [a trial period](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier)).

Links to GCP officlal docs below might help you get started:

- [Create storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)
- [Connecting to Cloud Storage Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/storage-buckets)